# Does Sharing Rule Prevent Role Hierarchy

Tags: sharing

I used a sharing rule to provide the subordinate role (Inside Sales) to have Read/Write access to the accounts of the role above it (Admin).  It works, but now the users of Inside sales cannot edit the accounts of the users in the roles below them.  As they could before....  How do I make it so the Inside sales can read/write to the roles above and below them?

Answer (score 2):

Sharing is cumulative; a sharing rule cannot reduce access provided by another means, such as the role hierarchy. As long as the users in a hierarchy are above others, they should still retain the same permissions. Either you're checking the wrong accounts, or you've found a bug that needs to be investigated by Support. There's no way to remove access to accounts owned by subordinates, since this feature is always enabled for standard CRM objects (e.g. Accounts). You can read more about this feature in [Controlling Access Using Hierarchies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&type=5).

Comment: Can users at the same level view/edit each other's records?

Comment: @Boots not without setting up sharing rules or other configurations. The role hierarchy only lets users see records for those *below* them. Sharing is a complicated subject.

Answer (score 0):

Since in the sharing rule, you have selected `Share with = Role` that's why the record is `Read Write` access to that particular users.

If you want the users below that role should have `Read Write` access then choose `Share with = Roles and Internal Subordinates`.

After changing this configuration, be sure to click on <kbd>Recalculate</kbd> button so that this role based visibility & access rights come into effect.

Comment: When I Edit the Sharing Rule There's no option to change the 'Share Withs' The fields are disabled.  I created a new sharing rule.  I configured it as follows: 
Account: owned by members of Role and Subordinates: Admin and Share with Role: Inside Sales. Now, the roles below Inside sales can see everything above (Admin).

Answer (score 0):

Sharing will always provide you more access. There is no way to restrict access by writing sharing rules. I think in your scenario -

- You will be able to edit Accounts owned by **Admin** because of the criteria based sharing rule.
- You will be able to edit Accounts owned by user with role below **Inside Sales** because **Grant Access Using Hierarchies** is always enabled by default for Standard objects(Account here)

Here is what I did to test this in my org

- **Role Hierarchy**

[image]

- **Criteria Based Sharing Rule**
  [image]